# Why init method for creating an instance of Struct Image is at extension of Image not at Struct Image?

Tags: swift, swiftui

The init method for creating an instance of Text is at 'Struct Text',

```
public struct Text : Equatable {

@inlinable public init(verbatim content: String)

public init<S>(_ content: S) where S : StringProtocol


public init(_ key: LocalizedStringKey, tableName: String? = nil, bundle: Bundle? = nil, comment: StaticString? = nil)


public static func == (a: Text, b: Text) -> Bool }
```

the init method for creating an instance of VStack is at 'Struct VStack '

```
public struct VStack<Content> : View where Content : View {

@inlinable public init(alignment: HorizontalAlignment = .center, spacing: CGFloat? = nil, @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content)

public typealias Body = Never }
```

, the init method for creating an instance of Button Struct is at 'Struct Button'

```
public struct Button<Label> : View where Label : View {

public init(action: @escaping () -> Void, @ViewBuilder label: () -> Label)

public var body: some View { get }

public typealias Body = some View }
```

BUT WHY IN CASE OF Image, the init method for creating an instance of Image Struct is at the extension of Image? `

```
extension Image {   
public init(_ name: String, bundle: Bundle? = nil)


public init(_ name: String, bundle: Bundle? = nil, label: Text)

public init(decorative name: String, bundle: Bundle? = nil)

@available(OSX, unavailable)
public init(systemName: String) }
```

`

Comment: I think it's probably due to the personal styles of whoever wrote them...